# Web App iOS swipe to see previous page

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, web-app-manifest

I just added a web app manifest to my web app in order to have a better mobile experience.

When I now add my web app to my iOS home screen everything looks just like a real app, but unfortunately right and left swipe to jump to the previous seen page is not working anymore. It seems to be disabled.
Is there a way to enable this again?
When running the web app in safari the swipe gesture works just fine.

In my web app manifest I have 
"display": "standalone" set.

I do not want to show the browser controls, it is supposed to look like a real app.

Is there a way to have the swiping enabled anyways again?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I never remember having this, but check out Framework7.io, they can do that with their framework